# Unusual SqlException when initiating connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, stored-procedures

I have a number of customers who can connect to our database without problems. One of our customers had to install our program fresh after he received a new computer and he's not able to successfully connect.

The connection process involves a stored procedure which checks a username, password and some other details and returns true if that user is allowed to use the database. The call to the stored procedure is where it goes wrong.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was
>   successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred
>   during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - Das Format
>   der empfangenen Nachricht war unerwartet oder fehlerhaft.)

That last bit is in German - it translates to

> The format of the message received was unexpected or incorrect.

I've snipped the rest since it's long. [Here's the rest as an image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k2nB.jpg) Sorry - I don't have it as text.

I've already tried

- having the user restart his machine
- restarting the SQL server
- checking that TCP/IP, named pipes and shared memory are enabled on SQL server

SQL Server version info:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)   Jun 28 2012
>   08:36:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with
>   Advanced Services (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: )

Everyone else seems to have no problems connecting as usual, but it's just this one customer.

Now, one thing that's odd is it states the provider is 'SSL Provider'. As far as I know, I'm not using SSL. Could the client think it's SSL when it's not, and that's causing unexpected data?

I'm running out of things to try - any ideas how I should proceed in troubleshooting?

Comment: Do you have .Net Framework 4.5.1 installed?

Comment: @Giorgi: as far as I know, the customer has the necessary Framework versions installed. Would this make a difference?

Comment: see this bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/812073/net-framework-4-5-1-breaks-ado-net-connections-to-sql-server

Comment: @Giorgi: customer reports that this indeed solves the problem. If you like you can make an answer (instead of a comment) and I'll accept it. You deserve the credit - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in .Net Framework 4.5.1 [.NET Framework 4.5.1 breaks ADO.NET connections to SQL Server](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/812073/net-framework-4-5-1-breaks-ado-net-connections-to-sql-server) You can solve the issue by installing .Net Framework 4.5.2

Comment: Thank you very much, Giorgi!